# The method 'setLocale' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'. - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to change my app language using buttons, i have set up the internationalization correctly and my app is working based on the system locale or language, now i want the user to change the language by pressing button.

so basically i found a solution for that in which i need to convert the "MyApp" widget in my main.dart file to stateful widget then create a setState method to update the state of locale property, here is the main.dart code:

```
import 'package:athaddakapp/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
  static _MyAppState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Locale _locale = Locale('ar', '');

    void setLocale(Locale value) {
      setState(() {
        _locale = value;
      });
    }

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Login',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        ),
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
          Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
        ],
        locale: _locale,
        home: LoginScreen());
  }
}
```

and this is the code when i want to change the language from the button:

```
changeLanguage() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(child: Text("choose language")),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context)!.setLocale(Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'en')),
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  height: 50,
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "English",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  height: 50,
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "عربي",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

the errors appears here : `onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context)!.setLocale(Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'en'))`

now am not sure what type exactly "MyApp" widget should be and how to change its type. ill be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the set locale function inside the build function. Move it outside the build to outside the class like this :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    Locale _locale = Locale('ar', '');
    void setLocale(Locale value) {
        setState(() {
            _locale = value;
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
    }
}
```